# How to get the results of multiple iterations in one dataframe when crawling with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Wondering if you could help please. Python newbie here.

I am crawling multiple urls in the one script, but it's returning 3 dataframes. One for each iteration.

What I am looking to achieve is one single dataframe that contains the URLs from each iteration.

What I have so far is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def get_links(url):

    links = []
    website = requests.get(url)
    website_text = website.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_text)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))

    data = (link in links)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(links)
        
    display(df)
    
get_links('https://www.example.com/')
get_links('https://www.example2.com/')
get_links('https://www.example3.com/')
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: are you calling the same host or different domains ?

Comment: Hi, for different domains.

Comment: check below answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should let the function return the dataframe instead of only display it

and then you should combine the outputs like that

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

# Reason Behind using `SoupStrainer` is to increase performance to parse only `a` tags.

# https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#soupstrainer

urls = ['Link1', 'Link2', 'Link3']


def get_links():
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        links = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
        for link in links:
            print(link.get('href', 'N/A'))


get_links()
```